# I'm trying to change the background-image using jQuery and it's works in my local machine but not working on serve online

Tags: jquery, css, replace

I'm trying to change the background-image in a DIV, the ideia is change a static image .png to a .gif on mouse over, and I don't know why it's working on my machine using MAMP, but when I put on my server in Hostgator, my code doesn't works, and the error appears in console is: **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'background.replace')**

My html is:

```
<ul class="items"  id="lista1">

            <li>
            <div class="bg-img" id="featured" id="featured" style="background-image: url('img/thumbs/tb_nesfit.png');">
              <div class="bgshadow_thumb" id="fshadow"></div>
              <div class="text-thumb">
                <div class="bottom">Cookies Nesfit</div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <a href="project.php?job=nesfit-cookies">
              <div class="content">
                <div class="content-info">
                  <button class="ico"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
                  <h2>Cookies Nesfit</h2>
                  <h3><span class="category">Animação, Simulação</span> | 2018</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="content-buttons">
                  <button class="ico"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></button>
                  <button class="ico"><i class="far fa-clock"></i></button>
                  <button class="ico"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
</ul>
```

and my jquery is:

```
$('li').mouseover(function() {

      var background = $(this).find("div#featured").css('background-image');
      background = background.replace('.png','.gif');
      $(this).find("div#featured").css('background-image', background);


           //var background = $(this).find("div#featured").css('background-image');
           //background = background.replace('.png','.gif');
           //$(this).find("#featured").css('background-image', background);

       });
```

I have a layer with shadow above this div, so I'm put mouseouver in 



 but I want change the DIV id= "Featured" where's my background-image is.

**JSFiddle my CODE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/theangelis/dL86r7nt/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=dL86r7nt

Comment: @Rodrigo_de_Angelis but works fine in my browser

Comment: Works fine in the fiddle. Is it possible that your host is blocking the image because it's an insecure resource (i.e., http) requested over a secure connection (i.e., https)?

Answer (score 0):

> $(this).css('background-image', 'url(/images/client_box_grad.gif)');

You should make sure that you have specified a valid image url.